# JavaScript function returning undefined in console

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm trying to return a value to console through this function. But the function is just returning "undefined" in the console of the associated HTML file.

```js
  function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood) {
   var animals = Number(numAnimals);
   var food = Number(avgFood);
   if (isNaN(animals)|| animals<0) {
    return null;
   }else if(isNaN(food)|| food<0){
    return null;
   }else{
    var total= animals*food;
    return total;}}
```

Comment: What are the input variables you are using for `numAnimals` & `avgFood`?

Comment: This is working! But `isNan` should be `isNaN`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to run this function:

```
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood) {
    var total = numAnimals * avgFood;
    return isNaN(total) || total < 0 ? false : total;
}
console.log(calculateFoodOrder(1, 10));
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L6yvmy1y/2/

Comment: instead of `isNan` i would suggest to use `(total !== total)` to detect `NaN`. Only for a `NaN` the above mentioned condition will be true. Also `isNan` is not reliable becuase `isNaN("Varun")` will return true

Comment: Um no...I don't think you're understanding how the function works. You might want to look at it again or click the sample. You seem a bit confused.

Comment: if by function you mean isNan(), check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN. In the end ti clearly mentions why isNan() is not reliable